# Remove extra space around heading element

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove ALL space around a `<h2>` element

I have this simple markup:

```
<div>
    <h2>Count down</h2>
</div>
```

I tried to remove spacing with:

```
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

But some white space remains. You can see it on this screen shot: 
[image]

There's spacing both over and under (and it's not padding or margin). How can I get rid of that extra spacing?

**EDIT:** Here is a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv8xgy3v/) to illustrate. I want to remove the space colored light blue.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't reproduce this based on solely the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The inspector in the screenshot shows

```
.countdown h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

which equates to:

```
.countdown h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

That means you must have a styled `h2` somewhere in your css.

Because the style is nested as `.countdown h2`, it will take precendent over just styling `h2` by itself.

If you cannot delete it, and would rather not use `!important` to override it, you may be able to override the style like:

```
body .countdown h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This gives it three elements, making it more specific than the two in the inspector. See an example of how it works here:  [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpej3rrh/)

---

**More on CSS precedence:**  [W3 - The cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade)

Comment: Yes I have 10px bottom margin on h2. That's the brown stuff in the image! I'm trying to remove the other (blue) space over and under.

Comment: It doesn't looks like any of the h2 styles you have in the question are being applied. Wherever you applied the `margin-bottom`, I would apply those styles. But I would apply  `line-height: 1;` instead of `line-height: 0;`. Also, in your updated example with the fiddle, you are styling an h2, but your html has an h1. I updated it with line height and styling an h2 here: https://jsfiddle.net/dv8xgy3v/1/

Comment: You can also apply line-height to the decimal as desire if `line-height: 1` still leaves too much space. Like `line-height: .8`: https://jsfiddle.net/dv8xgy3v/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help @dwreck08. It seems line-height is the way to go. I updated my fiddle. I want the element below to touch the bottom (or as close to as possible) the text. Margin and Padding alone wont do. It just feels wrong to manually to set line-height below 1. Is this a CSS bug?

Comment: Nope, setting the line height to 1 just means that you want to set each line within the element to match the height of the text. Setting it to zero would basically mean the text would lay on top of each if it were to wrap. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dv8xgy3v/7/

Answer (score 0):

you have `padding` on your countdown class which surrounds your h2 of `40px` as you made it global it will put padding on top bottom left and right at `40px` to fix try this

```
.countdown { padding:0px 40px 0px 40px; }
```

if you mean the h2 has space at the bottom thats because you have a style on it putting margin of 10px at the bottom to remove just delete that style.

```
.countdown h2 { margin: 0 0 10px; }
```

if you dont want to delete it you can overide it by doing

```
 h2 {
     margin: 0px !Important;
     padding: 0px;
     line-height: 0;
   }
```

you should not really use the `!important` unless really needed which in this case it is not.

Comment: The Chrome Inspector (see image) shows no padding. The 10px margin-bottom is intended (brown space in the image). Im trying to remove the blue stuff. Or at least understand where it's coming from.